# How to gather application logs which are generating in custom path using EFK

Tags: kubernetes, elasticsearch, fluentd, centralized-logging

I created the elasticsearch and kibina setup which is running outside the kubernetes cluster and i am using fluentd to gather kubernetes logs and to send data to elasticsearch. I am running fluentd as a deamonset in kubernetes.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  namespace: efk
  name: fluentd
  labels:
    app: fluentd
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fluentd
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fluentd
    spec:
      serviceAccount: fluentd
      serviceAccountName: fluentd
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.4.2-debian-elasticsearch-1.1
        env:
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            value: "HOST_IP"
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            value: "9200"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME
            value: "http"
          - name: FLUENTD_SYSTEMD_CONF
            value: disable
          - name: FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_PARSER_TYPE
            value: /^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr) [^ ]* (?<log>.*)$/
          - name: FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_EXCLUDE_PATH
            value: /var/log/containers/fluent*
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

But with this code i am able to gather only kubernetes node level logs, I want to gather logs from application pod from a specific path eg: /tmp/logs/* This is the path my application generating the logs.

To do this just running fluentD as Deamonset works or do we need to run fluentD as sidecar for all the application pods ?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your DaemonSet configuration to include FluentD configuration that tail specific log paths on the host node. This involves editing the FluentD configuration to include specific path patterns you want to monitor and setting up hostPath volume mounts for those paths in the DaemonSet YAML.

```
containers:
  - name: fluentd
    image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.4.2-debian-elasticsearch-1.1
    env:
      # FluentD configuration for log collection
    volumeMounts:
      - name: varlog
        mountPath: /var/log
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
      - name: tmplogs
        mountPath: /tmp/logs  # Mount path for your application logs
        readOnly: true
volumes:
  - name: varlog
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log
  - name: varlibdockercontainers
    hostPath:
      path: /var/lib/docker/containers
  - name: tmplogs
    hostPath:
      path: /path/to/your/application/logs
```